# Group by name, then select one document of each name with highest arbitrary field value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Let's say we have a collection containing the following documents:

```
[
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type A', 'version': 1, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type B', 'version': 1, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type B', 'version': 2, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type B', 'version': 3, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type C', 'version': 1, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type C', 'version': 2, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type A', 'version': 2, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type B', 'version': 4, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type A', 'version': 3, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type B', 'version': 5, ...},
]
```

I want to return a list containing the documents with the highest version for their respective name, such that the return would look like this, essentially returning the $$ROOT for each distinct name with the highest version:

```
[
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type A', 'version': 3, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type C', 'version': 2, ...},
    {'_id': ..., 'name': 'Type B', 'version': 5, ...},
]
```

I know that I need to use the aggregation pipeline, using group sort and limit, but I can't seem to get what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$sort` by `version` in descending order
- `$group` by `name` and get first root document from grouped
- *(optional)* `$replaceRoot` to replace `root` object to root

```
pipeline = [
  { $sort: { version: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$name",
      root: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$root" } }
]

result = db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aRwjOO5YrT7)